# Example of function that is not $L^1$ such that Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are not equal

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> What would be an example of  function that is **not** $L^1$ such that
>   Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are not equal?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing. If the function is not in $L^1$, then the Lebesgue integral is not defined.

Comment: @Boby if you want riemann integral to exist and not the other then sinc function does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are always equal whenever both exist, and if the Riemann integral exists then so does the Lebesgue integral. If a function is not in $L^1$, then its Lebesgue integral doesn't exist.

There are "improper" integrals that do not exist as Lebesgue integrals because the positive and negative parts integrate to infinity, but when you take the Riemann integral of those over the whole line most of the Riemann sums don't converge. In that case you have to take a limit, which is not really a Riemann integral. You could replace the Riemann integral with the Lebesgue integral in the limit and get the same answer.

Comment: So, for example $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(x) dx 0$ but Lebesgue is not defined. Would this example work?

Comment: No, but as suggested $\sin(x)/x$ does.

Comment: are there other examples rather then $sinc$?

Comment: Any function where the limit of the integral exists but the limit of the integral of the absolute value approaches infinity.